# Losing confidence after a series of paper rejections

Tags: publications, research-process, postdocs, emotional-responses

I don't think I have a concrete question to ask but I want to hear other researchers' opinions. I am pretty sure that there are many researchers who went through this and others will go through it in the future unfortunately.

I am a postdoc researcher with a limited contract and aim to apply for professorship positions. Therefore, I am actively submitting papers (working more than my contracted hours as there are no PhD students to co-supervise and publish papers with) to come up with a good and long list of publications. However, a lot of my papers are getting rejected with a huge disparity in the reviewers' scores. As a reviewer in almost all conferences I submit my work to, I find that my submission is better or equal to top accepted papers (I don't know whether this is a bad lcuk or just an illusion).

I focus mainly on top conferences with acceptance rates of less than 30% or 25%. I was almost sure that my last paper would be accepted because I am an expert in the area and because I learnt to assess paper quality, but it got rejected a few days after another rejection. Now, I am doubting my research capability (although I used to publish easily to these conferences when I was a PhD student). I am wondering whether I am a bad researcher or just an unlucky author.

Comment: You do not mention your supervisor at all. What is their role in this story? Are they co-authors of your submissions? Have they checked your work?

Comment: @Capsule In that case I will rephrase the question: do you have (former) colleagues, co-authors, or other people that can help you getting the paper published (by proof-reading, suggesting a journal or venue, critically reading the paper, ....)

Comment: I am assuming you are in computer science and in Australia?  People should stop using A*.   In my opinion, an acceptance rate of >20% is not A*.  It's more like B, 'A' at most.

Comment: Just keep at it. Either it will start to work out or it won't. That's how life is, it isn't unique to academia.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is a complaint and not a question.

Answer (score 5):

This sounds like a pretty common case of the human condition.  In my single days, I used to think of dating like "strikes and gutter balls".  That is, either I was getting many dates in rapid succession or going through a prolonged dry spell.  In the former, I was feeling pretty good about myself and was quite down in the latter.

In my current research days, I find a similar emotional oscillation.  This is the nature of research, in my opinion, and it builds character.  You actually sound quite productive, and the results will come.  In fact, I would encourage you to try to get more enjoyment from the process of seeking truth rather than putting all your eggs on the often opaque 'accept/reject' decision.  If I may with another analogy, it's like learning golf.  It's a slew of mishits, duffs, shanks, slices, hooks, flubs, and ineptitude until suddenly you smash a beauty down the fairway and are the envy of your friends.  If the one great shot makes up for the many bad shots, you're hooked.  If not, you're probably going to quit.

Also, pragmatic advice holds: get sleep, review diet, practice self-care, take mental health breaks, seek advice from colleagues/advisors, confirm writing and presentation adequately represents results, etc.

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that you are neither a bad researcher nor an unlucky author. The repeated rejections you describe are common in academia: even for the best postdocs it can be a long process to get papers accepted, and it is really (really really) hard to get a professorship (depending on the country and field of study).

Of course it is hard to know what is going on without further information, but reasons for the rejections could be, for example:

- a less than perfect match between conference/journal subject and submitted paper,
- a research subject that is not "fashionable" enough to be accepted by the best journals and conferences,
- conference organisers and journal editors could be biased towards people they know or have met before,
- you are focussing too much on A* conferences, maybe accepting a "lesser" conference or journal could get you started,

Also, there is more than one way to get a professorship: experience in the private sector is often highly valued, getting noticed during a non-tenured teaching position (with a percentage of time allocated for research) is a possibility, and looking for positions outside your home country could also help (if your personal circumstances permit this, of course).

In addition, there are other very nice jobs that are not professorships (arguably, there are many better jobs). It is not a failure to find a job in the private sector or to take a different (research or non-research) position at a university. It may help to look a little broader than focussing on the professorship alone.

Finally, as mentioned in the comments and other answer(s): get some rest: working 16 hours per day is not healthy and not productive. You (anybody) will perform better when they are well rested. It is better to focus and concentrate for 8 hours per day (or even less) and you will get more done than in 16 hours while tired.

Comment: It is not as hard to go from academia to the private sector as people say, although you may need to prove your skills with a certificate or clear story. I think looking for alternatives could be beneficial for you.

Comment: @Capsule It sounds, then, like the real problem is that you're trying to get research done while having a full-time, intellectually-demanding, but non-research day job.  The solution is probably to change the day job - maybe apply for part-time post-doctoral research associate positions, then when you get one, go part-time on the teaching role, or even apply for full-time PDRA positions, then when you get one, ditch the teaching role altogether.

Comment: ... or, if you feel like being really drastic, switch day jobs to one that's completely non-academia-related, but part-time.  In my area, pretty much _any_ other job pays better than the sort of teaching role you're in now, so it may be possible to do this without taking much of a drop in income.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called a bad researcher or an unlucky author. Getting a paper published or in general, having a successful career is less to do with sheer talent or hard work and more to do with management. Most successful academicians are excellent salesmen. And becoming an excellent salesman requires training.

My Ph.D. supervisor has 1000 papers to his name and sits on numerous committees and gets a felicitation every odd year. He has close to $15M funding currently. He gets funding not because of his technical expertise but because of his mastery in writing, connections, and excellent man-management. I hate that but it is the system we work with.

He is a bad researcher but a highly successful academician. I say bad because I did my Ph.D. under him and had to ignore him and rely on my co-supervisor because he simply does not know any of his research areas in-depth; but could talk for hours on the future possibilities, research trends, and research directions like an expert. He spends all his time collecting specific keywords from his connections and thanks to his excellent communication skills knows how to weave a story to get the funding.

My supervisor is an extreme case. But to be a good academician you need to get many things right. So firstly start collaborating. Appear as a second or third or tenth author in a number of papers. Look for A* conferences but also submit some ideas to A- and B-ranked conferences. Start building a citation network. It is criminal to engage in I cite you-You cite me, but this is how a large number of academicians thrive. You need a high H-index in your job application and for future promotions.

You are living on the other extreme. Spending long hours in a dingy room, alone working like a mad scientist won't get you anywhere. You may be good at what you do but that is simply irrelevant.

Find a balance between these two extremes. Once you are established as an academician, focus on your research, your style. You need to spend a few years doing this drill.  Who knows, maybe a Turing award or a Nobel awaits you. But, even Nobel laureates or other award winners, win their prize only when recommended by their colleagues: People like my supervisor.

Be it academia or any business only people who communicate, collaborate, and establish quid pro quo relationships, thrive. Talent, scientific expertise, in-depth knowledge of a field are secondary.

In conclusion, it does not matter if you are a good or bad researcher. You need to take certain actions to become a successful academician. And believe me, those actions are a lot easier than solving a complex problem, which I assume you are good at.

Best of luck!

Comment: Whenever I criticize academia in this forum it gets down voted. Truth hurts.

Comment: This answer is too cynical. It presents some outliers as the norm in academia. I'm not saying that it doesn't happen, but it is probably not the norm. And why would you want to play this game in academia when you can play it in the industry for a lot more money?

Comment: Unfortunately, they are not simply outliers. The majority of second-tier universities in the world follow these bad habits.

Comment: From your answer it seems like you believe that this behaviour is the mainstay of academia. If that were the case, these people should have been a majority in top-tier universities not just in second-tier universities.

Comment: It is clearly written that I am referring to my professor as an "extreme" case. Also, top-tier universities are far fewer in number. I suggest you read the response with an open mind. What is your experience in academia? You are sharing your opinion and I am sharing my experience. It's a harsh truth that academia, most of it, is mediocre across the spectrum. I know it hurts the academicians who read this.